# Create Android Signed APK without Eclipse . .

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have some requirements where I need to create android signed APK without eclipse .Anyone can guide is there any way I can do this ? I developed a project using eclipse . now I have complete project and I want to create its APK without eclipse . . .
star in advance -:)p.  .thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: You can use ant build-scripts to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the ant tool to do the build. Google has provided some documentation on how exactly you do this [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html). You could also look at [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html) for reference.